# Sobolev space $W^{1,2}((0,1))$ and boundary ODE - how does integration by parts goes?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

As a part of a question about $W^{1,2}((0,1))$, I want to get a boundary ODE on $g$ and don't quite know how to integrate (?) in order to get the equation.

let $g\in C^2[0,1]$ be our variable, $f\in W^{1,2}((0,1))$ a general function (my wish is that the following would be right for every $f$, for a (single) $g$ that would solve the equ. the equ is $f(0)=\int f\overline g + \int f'\overline g'$ (=$\langle f,g\rangle_{1,2}$)

**If it makes it easier for you to explain, don't think of that as $f(0)=$ but as $\langle f,g\rangle_{1,2}=$**

How can I get a differential equ from here? I believe I'd be able to solve and continue once I get it. I didn't quite know what  to do, but I mainly tried playing with integration by parts

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose any $g \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}[0,1]$ that is identically $1$ near $0$ and identically $0$ near $1$. Then, for any continuously differentiable $f$ on $[0,1]$, you have
$$
      f(0)=-fg|_{0}^{1} = -\int_{0}^{1}f(t)g'(t)+f'(t)g(t)\,dt.
$$
That's enough to give you constants $C$ and $D$ such that
$$
              |f(0)| \le C(\|f\|_{L^{2}}+\|f'\|_{L^{2}})\le D\|f\|_{W^{1,2}}.
$$
This functional $\Phi(f) = -\int_{0}^{1}f(t)g'(t)+f'(t)g(t)\,dt$ has a continuous extension to $W^{1,2}$. By the Riesz Representation Theorem, there exists $g \in W^{1,2}$ such that
$$
                        f(0) = (f,g)_{W^{1,2}}, \;\;\; f \in C^{1}[0,1].
$$
I'll let you fill in the details of what this means for a general $f \in W^{1,2}$. All the point evaluations in $[0,1]$ are continuous in the $W^{1,2}$ norm. $\mathbb{R}^{1}$ is a very nice and classical setting.

**Added**: To find the unique $g$ you're looking for,
$$
     \int_{0}^{1}fg+f'g'\,dt = \int_{0}^{1}fg-fg''\,dt+fg'|_{0}^{1} \\
            = \int_{0}^{1}f(g-g'')\,dt + f(1)g'(1)-f(0)g'(0).
$$
That means solving for $g$ such that
$$
                           g-g''=0,\;\; g'(0)=-1,\;g'(1)=0.
$$
The obvious solution is
$$
                       g(t)=\frac{1}{e-1/e}(e^{1-t}+e^{t-1})
$$

Comment: Thanks T.A.E.
I fairly understand why such $g$ should exists, and also why $\phi$ is a bounded operator that can be extended to $W^{1.2}$. The thing is that I would like to *find* such $g$, as explicitly as possible. That would require having some ODE and solving it, i believe

Comment: @Functional_Analysis : I've added what you want.

Comment: so easy, so elegant. thanks again T.A.E, you are the savior of the day